# Add more ckeditor on run time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to add as many ckeditors as I want but problem is that the clone ckeditors is just showing and freeze even not a single function is working on ckeditor

here is my code

```
<div class="row" id="single">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Description<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <textarea name="meta_description[]" class="form-control valid ckeditor" title="Plase enter Meta Description." placeholder="Meta Description" required></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="more">
          </div>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="add-more-btn">Add More</a>
```

here is jquery which clone to existing ckeditor

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#add-more-btn").click(function(e) {
            $( "#single" ).clone().appendTo( "#more" );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Both will have the same `id`. Wrong! Every editor need to have unique `id`. 2. You have to initialize CKEditor using something like: `CKEDITOR.replace( 'clone1' );` 3. Better to copy original code instead of replaced by CKEditor, so on `ready` (before CKEditor handle code) make clone to variable and use it.

Comment: done by my self using ckeditor adaptor. Thanks anyway @Krzysiek

Comment: Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/manektech/47htysb5/1/

Answer (score 1):

done by my self

```
<textarea name="description[]" class="form-control valid ckeditorJugar" title="Plase enter Meta Description." placeholder="Meta Description" required></textarea>

$( 'textarea.ckeditorJugar' ).ckeditor();

        $( "body" ).on( "click", "#add-more-btn", function() {
          $( '<textarea name="description[]" class="form-control ckeditorJugar"></textarea>' ).appendTo( "#more" );
          $( 'textarea.ckeditorJugar' ).ckeditor();
        });
```